# mat autocomplete не выбирается элемент, не работает автозаполнение

Tags: html, frontend, angular, angular8

Создал элемент в форме, загрузил из БД возможные значения.
Объекты отображаются, но 1) их нельзя выбрать 2) autocomplete не работает.
В задумке пользователю должны отображаться названия, а в качестве значений должны храниться id. Делал по примеру с офф сайта и статьи с англ версии stackoverflow, но не совсем вышло
Не могу понять в чем дело

html код компонента

```html
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Производитель" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="customer" name="customer" id="customer">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.id">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

TS код компонента

```js
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {
  addProductForm: FormGroup;
  message: string;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: Customer[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<Customer[]>;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private productsClient: ProductsClient, private router: Router,
              private customersClient: CustomersClient) {
                this.addProductForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  name: ['', Validators.required],
                  cost: ['', Validators.required],
                  customer: ['', Validators.required],
                  measure: ['', Validators.required]
                });
              }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customersClient.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
      this.options = data;
      this.filteredOptions = of(this.options);
    });
  }


  displayFn(customer?: Customer): string | undefined {
    return customer ? customer.name : undefined;
  }



  private _filter(name: string): Customer[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Вот так это выглядит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приводи в вопросах ссылки на _воспроизводимые примеры_ на codesandbox или stackblitz, а не скриншоты :)

Comment: @overthesanity пробовал я туда добавить что-либо и скажу вам, что проще человеку, который хочет помочь скинунь ссылку на github, чем пытаться создать там нормальный пример

Comment: Дружище, ну таковы правила форума...

Comment: @overthesanity, ну так и в коментах пишут чтобы помочь, а не нравоучением заниматься

Comment: Если тебя так задела моя просьба о том, что вместо скриншотов нужно приводить _воспроизводимые примеры_, то возможно тебе стоит для начала ознакомиться с правилами форума прежде чем задавать вопрос? [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)